# Detect a dropper with items in it without /testfor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was using this command to use a custom crafting table:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ dropper 1 {Items:[{id:minecraft:blaze_rod,Slot:1b,Count:1b,Damage:0s},{id:minecraft:blaze_rod,Slot:4b,Count:1b},{id:minecraft:stick,Slot:7b,Count:1b}]} /scoreboard players set @p LSC 1
```

But I get this error message when I stand on a dropper with these items:

> Failed to execute '{Items:[{id:minecraft:blaze_rod,Slot:1b,Count:1b,Damage:0s},{id:minecraft:blaze_rod,Slot:4b,Count:1b},{id:minecraft:stick,Slot:7b,Count:1b}]} /scoreboard players set @p LSC 1' as TrevMCC38

By the way, Im in 16w06a

Answer (score 4):

The `detect` function of `/execute` does not accept NBT data, only an ID and Damage value.

You will instead need to use `/testforblock`, and if needing multiplayer-friendliness, mixing it with CommandStats.

**Prerequisites:**

Objective to hold the CommandStats value.

```
/scoreboard objectives add CraftSuccess dummy
```

Applying the `AffectedBlocks` trigger to players, which will set the player's score based on the success of commands that specifically affect blocks, such as `/testforblock`. This may need to run on a clock in the event new players can join at any time.

```
/stats entity @a set AffectedBlocks @a[c=1] CraftSuccess
```

In order for CommandStats to modify a target's score, that target must be tracked on the scoreboard prior. This may also need to run on a clock for the same reason as before.

```
/scoreboard players add @a CraftSuccess 0
```

**Detection:**

The following must be run in numerical order.

1. Cause players to run the necessary `/testforblock` command.

   ```
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:dropper 1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",Slot:1b,Count:1b,Damage:0s},{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",Slot:4b,Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:stick",Slot:7b,Count:1b}]}
   ```
2. As a result, the executing player will have their own "CraftSuccess" score set equal to the number of blocks found by the `/testforblock` command. If the command failed, their score is set to 0. If the command succeeded, their score is set to 1. You'd then target players based on their score.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a[score_CraftSuccess_min=1] LSC 1
   ```

---

As a side-note, you should **never** mix `@a` as an executor and `@p` as the nested command's target if you're intended to target the same player. While `@a` can target dead players, `@p` cannot. That means that while the executor can run `/execute` while they're dead, they will not target themselves and instead target the nearest-living player. This can severely hurt accuracy and possibly break a target-sensitive mechanism.

The solution is to use the same selector when needed. For dead player targeting, you'd use `@a` as the executor with `@a[c=1]` as the nested selector:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /say @a[c=1]
```

For living-only players, you'd use `@e[type=Player]` with `@p`:

```
/execute @e[type=Player] ~ ~ ~ /say @p
```

It is also for this reason that CommandStat targets should use `@a[c=1]` when working with players, as this ensures there will not be an unintended target having their score modified.

Answer (score -1):

Use comparators because they detect if something has blocks in it and sends a redstone signal.

Answer (score -2):

No hacks are needed to test for  blocks with NBT in Minecraft 1.13 and newer versions:

```
/execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ dropper{Items:[{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",Slot:1b,Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:blaze_rod",Slot:4b,Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:stick",Slot:7b,Count:1b}]} run scoreboard players set @p LSC 1
```